# Is there any way to change text direction in table using python-docx?

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx

I read the doc of python-docx, but i don't find information how to change the text direction in the table.
[Doc page](http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/table.html)

And someone else, i can't find how to change a border width in document.

Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can get list of tables in the document by using following code:

```
doc = Document('filename.docx')
print(doc.tables)
```

Then you have to understand, which of the tables you need to modify (by position in the list or headers of the table or whatever applies). I will use the first table for simplicity. When you have you Table object you can modify cell values by doing:

```
table = doc.tables[0]
table.cell(0, 0).text = 'new value'
```

`python-docx` is base on the `microsoft office Openxml` format, please check the link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx
for more information.